# Replace text except in links

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a div (`contenteditable="true"`) which contains some html. I'm trying to replace text in the entire div *except* in links with a certain class.

I tried:

```
$('div#text').not('a.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).html = replaceFunction($(this).text))
});
```

But it doesn't replace anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector will never return anything. You are saying "give the div with id=text where it is not an a element with class=selected". Use `.children()` to get the children of the div.

`.html` and `.text` are methods. You can't assign to them. They have overloads for getting and setting:
`.html()` will get the html.
`.html(newhtml)` will set the html.

You want something like this:

```
$('div#text').children().not('a.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).html(replaceFunction($(this).text()));
});
```

Comment: sorry about the html() and text(), I wrote that too quickly :)

Comment: `$('div#text').children().not('a.selected')` can be simplified to `$('#text > :not(a.selected)')`

Comment: Should it work for text nodes ? $('div#text > :not(a.selected)').each() doesn't go inside the each()

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to set `.html` because it's a function defined by jQuery. Use

```
$('#text :not(a.selected)').each(function() {
  $(this).html(replaceFunction($(this).text())));
});
```

EDIT: I also noticed you were using `.text` as a value, but that too is a function. I've corrected it above to call `.text()` instead of treating it as a string.

EDIT2: Also, your selector is incorrect, fixed above. `div#text` can simply be `#text` as you shouldn't be using the id `text` twice on the page for another element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).html(replaceFunction($(this).text())));
```

You are not setting the html of the div .. But you just seem to assign the value to it.. Which does nothing..

Also missing `()`   for `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

In your code jQuery will find all divs with ID "text" (there are one) and then will remove from the resulting set all anchor elements with the class of "selected" (there are none).

If inside div#text all the content is wrapped in any kind of elements just try this:

```
$('div#text').children().not('a.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).html = replaceFunction($(this).text))
});
```

or less performant but all-levels finding

```
$('div#text').find("*").not('a.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).html = replaceFunction($(this).text))
});
```

You can also scan for all HTML nodes (including text nodes) using vanilla JS in a simple loop.